# Log-Likelihook and Softmax

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, log-likelihood

I need your help in understanding the following problem:

Given equations (80) and (78), one need to derive equation (81) using the chain rule from calculus, however from where does the $y_j$ comes from? since in either equations (80) and (78), this term does not appear there.
These equations are stated in [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html).

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the $j$th activation output be 
$$a_j=\frac{\exp(z_j)}{S},\;\;S=\sum_{t\in\mathcal{O}} \exp(z_t)$$
for outputs $\mathcal{O}$. The input is given by
$$
z_k = \sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}} w_{ki}\tilde{a}_i + b_k
$$
for inputs $\mathcal{I}$.
Then, the log-likelihood cost
$$
C = -\ln(a_y)= -\left[ \sum_{k\in\mathcal{I}} w_{yk}\tilde{a}_k + b_y \right] + \ln(S)
$$
with derivative
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial b_j} 
&= -\delta_{yj} + \frac{1}{S}\frac{\partial S}{\partial b_j}\\
&= -{y_j} + \frac{1}{S}\sum_{t\in\mathcal{O}}\exp(z_t) \frac{\partial z_t}{\partial b_j} \\
&= -{y_j} + \frac{\exp(z_j)}{S} \\
&= a_j - y_j
\end{align}
where $\delta_{yj}=y_j$ is the Kronecker delta.

The author remarks in a (cryptic) sidenote thet $y_j$ is the vector of zeros except at the $j$th position.